Change "Discount" title in order summary in cart
I am trying to change the "Discount" title to "Savings" in the order summary in cart.

I have tried modifying the following files and none of them seem to work.
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv
"Discount","Savings"

I've tried adding the same code below to these two files:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_SalesRule/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Savings</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</referenceBlock>

I've done all of the commands I normally do to get changes to show on my local site.

Am I completely off base here?

Well, I got partially there. I found the additional translations in vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/i18n/en_US.csv.
When I updated my en_US.csv files to include the below, I got it to change.
"Discount","Savings"
"Discount (%1)","Savings (%1)"
Discount,Savings

The issue I am not facing has to do when the order summary "refreshes" the word discount comes back. I will ask a separate question for that.
